# Entity Framework : Table with Composite Key issue : Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework with edmx & sql database.

I have 3 Tables: 1)Product 2)Language 3)ProductDesc

Now ProductID of Product table & LangID of Language table are used as foreign key in ProductDesc and "ProductID  + LangID" is composite key for ProductDesc table, ProductDesc table has 4 other desc columns & all are nvarchar.

now when I insert/update Product data, I am checking in 
code if ProductDesc  exist with ProductID P1 and LangID L1, it returns null and next lines of code tries to insert data in ProductDesc but gives error
**Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ProductDesc'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ProductDesc'**, whereas there is no record with that combination of ProductID and LangID in table ProductDesc.

```
var pDesc = db.ProductDescs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductID == ProductID && x.LangID == LangID);
if (pDesc == null)
{
    pDesc = new ProductDesc();
    pDesc.ProductID = ProductID;
    pDesc.LangID = LangID;
    db.ProductDescs.Add(pDesc);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

This works fine when I am doing Insert/Update data from UI for one product.

But when I am using same function for bulk data which are inserted from windows service it causes this error.
My windows service reads data from azure queue and call same function to insert data for each product.

And from windows service around 100 records inserted successfully and then this issue occurred

Comment: does your windows service use multiple threads to read data from the queue?

Comment: In service one thread started initially, after that inserting data whenever something comes from queue.

Comment: So probably there are duplicates in the input.

Comment: @GertArnold I checked logs there were no duplicate records found

Answer (score 0):

You Will get the Same Error of Primary Key Violation when there are duplicates exists in the Data That you are inserting.

Suppose I have a table Like this

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
(
 Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 Name VARCHAR(25)
)
```

I'm inserting a record with Id 1

```
INSERT INTO TableA
VALUES(1,'ABC')
```

It Will be inserted But Instead of the above, If I try to Insert 2 Records with the Same ID from the same Statement Like this

```
INSERT INTO TableA
VALUES(1,'ABC'),(1,'XYZ')
```

It Will Give me the Primary Key Violation error and Won't show any existing records on the Table.

So Make sure there are no Duplicates in your input Data

Comment: Yes I have check before inserting data var pDesc = db.ProductDescs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductID == ProductID && x.LangID == LangID);

Comment: Since you are doing the Bulk Insert, The Data Won't be committed Until the entire rows are inserted. So Just insert the Distinct Combinations of Your Key Columns

Comment: Here product data are comming from queue one by one and there is savechanges for each product.

Comment: Do you have a Transaction for Each insert? I Mean Begin and Commit ? or All changes are committed Together?

Comment: No there is no begin & commit. It work this way from queue read one message which is one product data and then insert/update that data in Product and ProductDesc table. One thing is I am calling repository function and creating repository object this way private static readonly MyDBEntities db = new MyDBEntities();
private static readonly Repository repository = new Repository(db);

Comment: I've never worked with entity framework. So It's hard for me to understand the Code in that.